# How do I make a user stay in a URL while a session is active?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to use PHP Session to keep a user in a specific url while a session is active, but I can't figure it out. I managed to keep users from accessing that url while no sessions are active but the vice versa, I can't make heads or tails of. Any ideas?

EDIT: To clarify, I mean while he's in a specific localhost url, he can't access other pages just by changing the url. He has to stay in that webpage till the session_destroy() function is called by pressing the logout button.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "keep a user in a specific url"?

Comment: Sorry, there's the edit.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want to suppress that the user edits the URL in his browser? What should happen if he does that? As `session_destroy` happens on the server, there's no simple way the browser can check that

Comment: @KadeTanaka could you explain taking example scenario may be?

Answer (score 1):

Use similar approach as with users without session:

If session exists and user tries to access different url - redirect back

```
if (isset($_SESSION['only_url']) && $_SESSION['only_url'] != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['only_url']);
    exit();
}
```